# onesignal send push to user like FCM

Tags: javascript, react-native, onesignal

I'm sending pushes with OneSignal in React Native app. I'm new with it, but have some experience with Google FCM. I'd like to make the same architecture solution like FCM.

1. Init -> `OneSignal.initialize("CODE")`;
2. Get device token -> I did not find any SDK API to get it.
3. Place token into database and link it with userid in my database.
4. Get token from database when action triggered and send push by token.

Please, help with 2 (get token API) and 4 statement (send push by Token API).